# Missing Parts When moving from Blender to 3D Print

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

Since all the good answers up here taught me a lot along my way into modelling, I'm coming back to you with a question:

I've been modelling a ring in blender and would like to print it with my Photon. I know it's quite fragile but the wires are as thick as the support columns.

1. One basic thing I never understood: When creating a mesh in blender, will I have to fill it in for printing or is this happening in the slicer?
2. When I'm trying to print (and also when making solid in MeshMixer) only one of the spirals is printed - can you help me what happened to the rest?

Link to the file: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give your question a meaningful title? People who can help you and those who have the same or a similar problem can find your question that way.

Comment: The file attachment is an STL file not a Blend file (Post the Blender fIle) another place to attach Blend file is https://blend-exchange.com/ .  Also when importing your STL file into Blender it crashes Blender.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RickT I attached the Blender File